# How do I split a list containing data frames into the individual data frames?

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr

I have 6 lists (`l1`,`l2`,`l3`,`l4`,`l5`,`l6`) in total and in each list, I have 12 dataframes (`df1`,`df2`,`df3`,...,`df10`,`df11`,`df12`). I would like to split all the lists. This is what I have tried.

```
split_df<-function(list){
for (i in 1:length(list)){
assign(paste0("df",i),list[[i]])}
}
```

It only works if I use the for loop only. But it doesnt work with the function.

Let's look at the following list, l1:

```
l1<-list(data.frame(matrix(1:10,nrow=2)),data.frame(matrix(1:4,nrow=2)))
split_df(l1)
df1
Error: object 'df1' not found
df2
Error: object 'df2' not found
```

But without the function:

```
for (i in 1:length(l1)){
assign(paste0("df",i),l1[[i]])}

df1
#   X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
# 1  1  3  5  7  9
# 2  2  4  6  8 10
df2
#   X1 X2
# 1  1  3
# 2  2  4
```

How do I rectify this?

Comment: Have you tried `list2env(mylst, .GlobalEnv)`?

Comment: @lukeA I tried `list2env(l1, .GlobalEnv)`. It gives `Error in list2env(l1, .GlobalEnv) : 
  names(x) must be a character vector of the same length as x`

Comment: Is the answer here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12215032/use-loop-to-split-a-list-into-multiple-dataframes ?  See @ptocquin 's answer, I think it's what you want.

Comment: Maybe put an `eval(as.symbol())` around `list` in the loop?

Comment: I believe the error comes from the list elements having no names. I did not see that. If you set the names, it will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use assign locally. So inside the function, you create the `data.frame`s `df1` and `df2`. You can assign these to the global environment instead:

```
split_df<-function(list){
  for (i in 1:length(list)){
    assign(paste0("df",i), list[[i]], envir = .GlobalEnv)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
l1<-list(data.frame(matrix(1:10,nrow=2)),data.frame(matrix(1:4,nrow=2)))
names(l1) <- paste0("df", seq_along(l1))
list2env(l1, .GlobalEnv)
```